# Crear boton para ejecutar en el terminal python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, botón, interfaz

Buenas noches una pregunta alguno no tendra codigo para crear un boton con la finalidad de ejecutar una hoja.py al momento de darle click?, osea no tener la nececidad de ir al terminal para ejecutarlo.Mas bien darle en el boton y que es ejecute?

Comment: ¿Un icono en el escritorio que lance el programa?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Si, osea que este en la pagina web y al momento de darle en el botton se ejecute un archivo de python en el terminal

Answer (score 0):

Crea un archivo .bat en la misma ruta de tu archivo .py, si estas en Windows y en el .bat escribes.

```
@echo off 
python script.py`
```

Comment: ok, entonces no tendria que insertar ninguna funcion?                                         con ese codigo ¿me permite crear boton en la pagina web?